# How to redirect and rewrite sign - into + in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have old web [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and new web [www.example2.com](http://www.example2.com).
The link to product in old web looks like : [www.example.com/dir/product-name-p-123.html](http://www.example.com/dir/product-name-p-123.html)
I would like redirects this to new web with this link : [www.example2.com/advanced_search_result.php?keywords=products+name](http://www.example2.com/advanced_search_result.php?keywords=products+name)

Can you help how I can do that ?

BR, Peter

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-p-*.html https://www.example2.com/advanced_search_result.php?keywords=$1 [QSA,L]

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution if the product name is composed by 2 parts splitted by - :

```
RewriteRule ^dir/([^-]*)\-([^-]*)(-p.*)$ advanced_search_result.php?keywords=$1-$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but directory dir is different for the products and the product name can have more than 2 words.

Comment: This work for products name with 3 words : RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^-]*)\-([^-]*)\-([^-]*)(-p.*)$ https://www.example2.com/advanced_search_result.php?keywords=$2+$3+$4 [R=302,QSA,L]